# Is winter of Bangkok very cold?

Tags: weather-and-climate, winter, bangkok

Is it true that Bangkok can be very cold in winter? If so,when would it be very cold and how cold can it be?

Comment: Where have you heard that? I suppose it depends a bit on where you come from/your frame of reference but generally it's not cold, let alone *very* cold at any time of the year. Not sure "winter" is the right word, incidentally, it's not a four-season temperate climate.

Comment: I doubt any country in the tropics is cold unless you increase the altitude.

Comment: Some places that people assume are tropical and assume are at normal altitude turn out not to be. Mexico City is a prime example. Also people from the tropics start rugging up at temperatures other people can consider quite warm. For all I know OP is from somewhere closer to the equator and at a lower altitude than BKK (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Bangkok is 5m over sea level. But otherwise agreed, people have quite different comfort zones. Judging from the answers, Bangkok's coldest days are warmer than normal days in temperate summers, though.

Comment: which tropical countries have 4 seasons/winter?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: For starters, countries which have tropical parts and non tropical parts. Australia, for instance.

Comment: how could you not find any information on that subject? like, basically, the wikipedia article on bangkok, section climate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangkok#Climate

Comment: [If one of these explodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uxycc9MPhZU) then you may experience temperatures near the freezing point in Bangkok.

Answer (score 23):

My favourite resource for such questions is [weatherspark](http://weatherspark.com), which tells me that [for Bangkok](https://weatherspark.com/averages/33955/Samut-Prakan-near-Bangkok-Chon-Buri-Thailand):

> Over the course of a year, the temperature typically varies from 23°C
>   to 35°C and is rarely below 20°C or above 36°C.
>
> ...
>
> The *cold* season lasts from November 18 to January 31 with an average
>   daily high temperature below 32°C. The coldest day of the year is
>   January 6, with an average low of 23°C and high of 32°C.

Which for me is 'not very cold', but your internal thermostat may be set differently...

Comment: I think they meant "the 'cold' season".

Answer (score 4):

[This link tells me that Bangkok has cool weather between December and February.](http://www.bangkok.com/weather.htm#promo) (not cold or freezing). [This link has preserved the temperature data over the last few years in Bangkok city.](https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VTBD/2016/1/30/MonthlyHistory.html?req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=) Since you did not mention which month you will be going, I suggest you feed in the month data and choose the year and see how it was.

Comment: Here "cool" means "some days in the evening it may drop below 20C,"  which is 68F.

Comment: Yeah Bangkok's evening "winter" temperatures are higher than Northern Europe's summer temperatures... it's the middle of July, at the hottest time of the day, and it's 19c here. 20c and below is just about the point where you might want to wear trousers instead of shorts

Answer (score 3):

**Not very cold.** As a Thai living in Bangkok I would say that central Thailand rarely has cold winter. Normally, it is above 15°C throughout winter and above 25 downtown (last year was an exception as downtown Bangkok reached 16). I think the weather won't be your problem if you plan to visit central Thailand in the winter.

Comment: Honestly, temperatures like that would certainly be a problem for me.